# active admin image field is shown dirty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am using ActiveAdmin gem for admin console in ROR application. In my ActiveAdmin model-FeaturedEvent i have declared form for creating Featured event. FeaturedEvent model as a image field so i tried writing it. but it says NoMethodError in Admin::FeaturedEvents#new undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass. Following is my ActiveAdmin Model:

```
ActiveAdmin.register FeaturedEvent do
permit_params do
permitted = [:name, :location, :start_time, :description,:image,:phone, :email, :event_url, :active, :free, :image, :s3_credentials]
permitted << :other if params[:action] == 'create'
permitted
end

controller do
def create 
    byebug
    @featuredevent = Event.new(permitted_params[:featuredevent])

    if @featuredevent.save
        redirect_to '/admin/featured_events#index'
    else
        flash[:message] = 'Error in creating image.'
    end


end

def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :location, :start_time, :description,:image,:phone, :email, :event_url, :active, :free, :image, :s3_credentials)
end
end

form do |f|
inputs 'Create Private Events' do

  input :image
end

actions do
    button_to  'Create', featured_speakers_path(:featuredevent), method: :post
            #link_to 'Create', {:controller => 'events', :action => 'create'}, {:method => :post }
end 
end

end
```

Error in browser on navigating to create featured event:

```
**NoMethodError in Admin::FeaturedEvents#new**
undefined method `dirty?' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: are you using paperclip..??

Comment: Ok i got it. Paperclip needs a different name for attachment declaration in FeaturedEvent model [I have other model in which image was used ]. Thank you Vishal

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it. Paperclip needs a different name for attachment declaration in FeaturedEvent model [I have other model in which image was used ]. Thank you Vishal

Comment: wc bro :) my pleasure :)